# Filter Dataframe by comparing one column to list of other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a dataframe with numerous float columns.  I want to filter the dataframe, leaving only the values that are inbetween the High and Low columns of the same dataframe.

I know how to do this when the conditions are one column compared to another column.  But there are 102 columns, so I cannot write a condition for each column.  And all my research just illustrates how to compare two columns and not one column against all others (or I am not typing the right search terms).

I tried `df=  df[ (df['High'] <= df[DFColRBs]) & (df['Low'] >= df[DFColRBs])].copy()`  But it erases everything.

and I tried `booleanselction =  df[ (df[DFColRBs].between(df['High'],df['Low'])]`

and I tried: `df=  df[(df[DFColRBs].ge(df['Low'])) & (df[DFColRBs].le(df['Low']))].copy()`

and I tried:

```
BoolMatrix =  (df[DFColRBs].ge(DF_copy['Low'], axis=0)) & (df[DFColRBs].le(DF_copy['Low'], axis=0)) 
df= df[BoolMatrix].copy()
```

But it erases everything in dataframe, even 3 columns that are not included in the list.

I appreciate the guidance.

Example Dataframe:

```
    High     Low    Close   _1m_21  _1m_34  _1m_55  _1m_89  _1m_144 _1m_233 _5m_21  _5m_34  _5m_55
0   1.23491 1.23456 1.23456 1.23401 1.23397 1.23391 1.2339  1.2337  1.2335  1.23392 1.23363 1.23343
1   1.23492 1.23472 1.23472 1.23422 1.23409 1.234   1.23392 1.23375 1.23353 1.23396 1.23366 1.23347
2   1.23495 1.23479 1.23488 1.23454 1.23422 1.23428 1.23416 1.23404 1.23372 1.23415 1.234   1.23367
3   1.23494 1.23472 1.23473 1.23457 1.23425 1.23428 1.23417 1.23405 1.23373 1.23415 1.234   1.23367
```

Comment: IIUC you want `DF_copy.le(DF_copy['High'], axis=0) & (DF_copy.ge(DF_copy['Low'], axis=0))`, i.e. the combined conditions of <= High and >= Low. This returns a matrix of true/false values, you can mask your matrix with `DF_copy.where()`, with the condition above, which by defaults replaces False with `NaN` but you supply an alternative.

Comment: Okay, But I only want to do the test on certain columns included in the list of column names DFColRBs.  There are 3 columns at the beginning (High and Low are 2 of them) that should not be affected by the bool index.  When I do as you suggest, I get the true/false matrix on the correct columns.  But when I do `DF_copy2 = DF_copy.where(mask)' , everything in df is turned to np.nan.  Even the 3 columns that are not included in the list of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've said in the comments, best to split the df into the pieces you want to operate on and the ones you don't, then use matrix operations.

```
tmp_df = DF_copy.iloc[:, 3:].copy()
# or tmp_df = DF_copy[DFColRBs].copy()

# mask by comparing test columns with the high and low columns
m = tmp_df.le(DF_copy['High'], axis=0) & tmp_df.ge(DF_copy['Low'], axis=0)

# combine the masked df with the original cols
DF_copy2 = pd.concat([DF_copy.iloc[:, :3], tmp_df.where(m)], axis=1)
# or replace with DF_copy.iloc[:, :3] with DF_copy.drop(columns=DFColRBs)
```

Comment: Thank you.  Works very well!.  So I was missing concat.  I didn't think of that.  Thanks for the help!